# phpMyAdmin error "Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed."

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I removed the root account in mysql in an attempt to harden the server.  I have created another user (let's call it AdminAccount) and granted all privileges on % and localhost.  Since then, I have been getting the following error when I login to phpmyadmin:

> mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
> 'AdminAccount'@'localhost' (using password: YES) Connection for
> controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

This error appears at the bottom of each screen although **I have not seen any loss of functionality** - all pages are working and I can work on any of the databases.  Here are the checks I did:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show grants for 'root'@'localhost';
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*48xxxxxxxxxxxxxx6' |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                               |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)
    
MariaDB [(none)]> show grants for 'root'@'%';
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'root' on host '%'
MariaDB [(none)]> show grants for 'AdminAccount'@'localhost';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for AdminAccount@localhost                                                                                                              |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `AdminAccount`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `phpmyadmin`.* TO `AdminAccount`@`localhost`                                                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show grants for 'AdminAccount'@'%';
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for AdminAccount@%                                                                                                              |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `AdminAccount`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*48xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

After this, I went ahead and added the following:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
MariaDB [(none)]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I also tried

```
DROP USER ''@'localhost';
DROP USER ''@'%';
```

based on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11216911/989468).  But I didn't have that problem and it said I don't have any such user.

Nothing has changed in phpmyadmin despite the above interventions.  What did I do wrong and how can I fix it?

My configuration:

```
Database server
    Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
    Server type: MariaDB
    Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
    Server version: 10.5.18-MariaDB-0+deb11u1 - Debian 11
    Protocol version: 10
    User: AccountAdmin@localhost
    Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4) 
Web server
    Apache/2.4.54 (Debian)
    Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.2.1
    PHP extension: mysqli curl mbstring 
    PHP version: 8.2.1

phpMyAdmin
    Version information: 5.1.4deb1~bpo11+1
```

**Edit:**
I found a potential problem.  I was told to look for the following:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'your_username';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'your_password';
```

in the config file for phpmyadmin.  However, in /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php those lines do not exist.  Instead I found the following:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = $dbuser;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = $dbpass;
```

but what is $dbuser and $dbpass?  I didn't find those variables anywhere in that file or in any other file.  I used grep to search all dirs and subdirs under /etc/phpmyadmin

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: OK. Sorry about that. I thought it would be the most accurate and succinct way to show the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was it. I added:

```
$dbuser = "AdminAccount";
$dbpass = "MyPassword";
```

and the error went away.

Surprising that such a "bug" exists in a (practically) pristine installation.  I looked at a lot of solutions before this and none of them worked.